# Is there a way to explicitly find any rational $\mathbb{F}_p$-curve on the Kummer surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces

Consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ (where $p \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$, $p \equiv 3 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4)$), $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$-isomorphic elliptic curves (of $j$-invariant $0$)
$$
E\!:y_1^2 = x_1^3 + b, \qquad E^{(1)}\!: y_2^2 + x_2^3 + b = 0, \qquad \mathrm{where \qquad } b \in \mathbb{F}_p^* \setminus (\mathbb{F}_p^*)^3,
$$
and the affine model 
$$
K\!: (x_1^3 + b)y^2 + x_2^3 + b \ \subset \ \mathbb{A}^3_{(x_1,x_2,y)}, \qquad \mathrm{where \qquad } y = \frac{y_2}{y_1},
$$
for the Kummer surface of their direct product.

Is there a way to explicitly find any rational $\mathbb{F}_p$-curve on $K$?

Comment: Must the curve be smooth (in which case the answer is encoded in the
Frobenius action on the Neron-Severi lattice), or would a singular
rational curve suffice for your purpose?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, a singular rational curve suffices for my purpose.